# How to count the products on a page using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

is there any way to count the all available products in a e-commerce web site?

below is the html.

[Cargo Pants](/parade/storeus/browse/productDetailColorSizePicker.jsp?navAction=jump&categoryNav=false&categoryId=cat70004&productId=xprod2517&navCount=4)

Comment: Can you elaborate your question.?

Comment: There is no HTML code.

Comment: Link is redirecting to error page

Comment: <p class="prod_name">
<a href="/storeus/browse/productDetailColorSizePicker.jsp?navAction=jump&amp;categoryNav=true&amp;categoryId=cat70004&amp;productId=xprod2517&amp;navCount=0">
Cargo Pants
</a>                                                                                                                                              
    This is the HTML

Comment: i am working on a e commerce project and in a product list we will have the list of products so i want count how many products are available please see the html of first product in the page

Comment: can you post exact URL that your using.

Comment: i can't post we are testing in local server.. the page looks like this http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/formal-shoes/pr?sid=osp%2Ccil%2Cssb&otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_men_0_Formal+Shoes

Comment: i haven't marked you down on this - but, it's a terrible question and you really need a few pointers on how to remedy this: 1. lay out the question by splitting it into describing the problem, followed by the solutions you have tried so far. 2. Include as small a fragment of code that you feel represents what you are fighting with. 3. add any additional informational links to aid in giving further non essential context to the question. As things stand, you've been lazy and wont get many great quality replies. The old adage holds true, sh!t in sh!t out - i really hope you see my point...

Comment: btw - my final sentence is NO reflection on any replies already offered - just to make that clear!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you are looking for, but in selenium there is a method to find elements in the browser:

```java
List<WebElement> wel = null;
String newElement = (element_to_locate);

wel = this.getDriver().findElements(By.id(newElement));
```

Comment: <p class="prod_name">
<a href="/parade/storeus/browse/productDetailColorSizePicker.jsp?navAction=jump&amp;categoryNav=true&amp;categoryId=cat70004&amp;productId=xprod2517&amp;navCount=0">
Cargo Pants
</a> This is the HTML

Comment: i am working on a e commerce project and in a product list we will have the list of products so i want count how many products are available please see the html of first product in the page

Comment: The link is not accesible. **Error 404**

Comment: <p class="prod_name"> <a href="/parade/storeus/browse/productDetailColorSizePicker.jsp?navAction=jump&amp‌​;categoryNav=true&amp;categoryId=cat70004&amp;productId=xprod2517&amp;navCount=0"‌​> Cargo Pants </a>   This is the HTML...

Answer (score 1):

Basically

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.id(repeating_element_ID));
int itemsCount = list.size();
```

where `findElements` is right function for resolve this issue, because it returns list of items located by By-locator (id, xpath, name, ...). Then you can count elements by function size() on given list.